# display loading message in php self submit form

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

I have any form for upload video, this worked using PHP / MySQL and submit **`PHP_SELF`** action. If upload video = TRUE I print video is success and if upload video = FALSE I print error message.

Now I need to show display loading message or loading gif animator (using jQuery) after clicking the submit button and hidding the loading message after showing the TRUE/FALSE upload message. Any way to create this?

My form:

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'uploadvideo')
     {
      //CHECK TRUE OR FALSE .....
     }
if (isset($uploaded) && $uploaded == TRUE){?>
     <div class="successbox">success upload!!!</div>
<?PHP } 
if (isset($uploaded) && $uploaded == FALSE)
    {?>
     <div class="errorbox">error upload!!!</div>
<?PHP } ?>

    <form action="<?PHP echo URL . '/video.php?id=' . int($_GET['id']);?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <input type="file" size="40" name="video_file" maxlength="50">
      <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="uploadvideo">
      </table>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest an quickest solution is to add a hidden `<div>` element to your form containing a loading message or animated gif, and when you click the submit button you show the `<div>` tag using jQuery:

```
<form action="..." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="$('#loading').show();">
  <div id="loading" style="display:none">Uploading...</div>

  <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <input type="file" size="40" name="video_file" maxlength="50">
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="uploadvideo">
  </table>
</form>
```

If you want something more fancy (like an actual progress bar) you'll need to look into a flash solution (like [swfupload](http://www.swfupload.org/)).

Starting with PHP 5.4 you can also find the upload progress in _SESSION ([more details here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php)) but seeing as PHP 5.4 is just released, you wont find many webhosts that already have this.

Comment: simple & worked. myform worked with ffmpeg . swfupload and any more plugin not work for me. thanks